# Does dart null safety variable need manual release?

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable, dart-null-safety

I defined some nullable objects and used them elsewhere in State<T>

```dart
List<T>? _data;
int? _count;
```

Do I need to release them manually?
like this:

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _data?.clear(); // clear list
    _data = null;   // blank manually
    _count = null;  // blank manually
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: no, you don't, dart will do it automatically